# How to distinguish “à cette heure” from “à sept heures”?

Tags: prononciation, indications-de-temps

How do I distinguish *à cette heure* from *à sept heures*, when pronounced?

It occurred to me when once I wanted to say "at this time", and then I realized I had just said "at 7".  I guess I probably should have used "en ce moment", right?

Comment: [_Le car pour Sète, il part à Caen?_](http://michel.buze.perso.neuf.fr/lavache/devos3.htm)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, when referring to "at this time", we can also say *À cette heure-ci, […]*.

Plus, *À cette heure* all alone sounds weird to me, I don't know.

*En ce moment* is right too though.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. `À cette heure` couold be used when describing an event, like in a newspaper. "At that time (hour), the policemen broke into the building"

Answer (score 2):

There should not be any ambiguity actually.

If during the conversation, a time was explicitly mentioned, people will understand *à cette heure* :

> — On se retrouve dimanche matin vers huit heures?
>
> — Oh là, à cette heure je serai encore au lit!

However, if you mention a time just out of the blue, it will be clear you mean *à sept heures*

> — On se retrouve dimanche matin?
>
> — À sept heures, ça te va?

Also, note that, in a rather formal or litterary context, *à cette heure* can also mean *right now*.

Comment: I find the first example much more ambiguous than any other I could have thought. How do you know that the guy didn't mean "at 7 I'll still be in bed"?

Comment: In the first example I would naturally use “à cette heure-là” — no risk of misunderstanding.

Comment: @RickyRobinson because if he meant "at 7", there should be a followup sentence, like "Oh là, à 7h je serai encore au lit, alors je pense pas que je pourrai être là à 8h!", otherwise, the statement is missing some sense.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Might be something regional then, I would naturally use and expect from others "à cette heure" :)

Comment: Except for in a written text, I think I will avoid all uses of "à cette heure" and limit myself to “à cette heure-là” or “à cette heure-ci”, depending on the context.